# Find commit with the smallest diff

Tags: git

I got sent a bunch of files originating from the same git repo I work with, but they were developed against an older commit. How to find out which commit they used? Something like least lines of diff.

Comment: Consult with the sender and see what commit the files were based on. I don't think there's any other reliable way if all you got was copies of the files from the working directory. Perhaps have them provide you a clone of their repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to find out which commit they used? Something like least lines of diff.

Well, you can do exactly that: find the commit with the smallest diff against your target directory.  Just run a loop over all the commits in your repository, and for each one compute a diff against your target directory, and remember the one with the smallest diff.

Let's assume you have your repository in `./repo` and the files in question in `./target`.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd repo
HEAD=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
git log --pretty='%H' | while read rev; do
    git checkout -q $rev
    lines=$(diff -ruN -x .git . ../target | wc -l)

    if ! [[ "$minlines" ]] || [[ $lines -lt $minlines ]]; then
        minlines=$lines
        commit=$rev
        echo "$lines $rev"
    fi

    [[ $lines -eq 0 ]] && break
done | tail -1

git checkout $HEAD
```

This will take a while for a repository with a long history, but it works.  It will print out the size of the diff followed by the commit id for the commit with the smallest diff.

If you interrupt this script while it's running you'll need to check out an appropriate branch head (e.g., `git checkout master`).

Comment: You can certainly find the commit that generates the smallest diff against the current files. But that has very little to do with what commit the files were base off to begin with.

Comment: @twalberg would you have a better idea?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a better idea, without getting different information from the original source, as I commented under the question. A copy of their repository, a manual check to see what their `HEAD` commit is, patches generated via `git format-patch` or some other form. Just getting a set of files from the work directory includes no metadata about what they looked like pre-modification, and that's the information you need to get it into the "right place" in your repository.

Comment: I have had to do exactly this on a couple of occasions, and it ultimately got me exactly what I needed: the commit on which the other set of files (in this case, a couple of RPM packages) were based.  I suspect it will get the OP what they want, too.  Of course, your mileage may vary, but if it works, let us know.

Comment: @larsks In many cases, it probably is correct, or nearly so, but it's entirely possible that by applying external patches or some other mechanism, the tree now more closely resembles a commit that isn't the one it was branched from. It will "work", and if you never push/fetch to other repositories, it may even never cause a problem, but it's not guaranteed to be exactly right... I can't say whether that's sufficiently good enough for OP, though - that's their call...

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer and nearly all comments are just being pedantic and missing the point.

I was faced with the same problem as the OP and after a bit of trial-and-error, I found the following one-liner helped me quickly narrow down a suspected base commit which upon visual inspection was very clearly within 2 or 3 commits of "the one".

You can then pin-point the correct base commit by reasoning about the logical sequence and purpose of the changes.

First, commit the incoming code into a new branch (i.e. make sure HEAD has the code you want to compare) and then run:

```
for hash in $(git log --pretty=format:%H); do echo "$hash: $(git diff HEAD..$hash --stat | wc -l)"; done
```

This will output two columns: hash and number of lines changed relative to HEAD.

Pick the commit with the smallest line-count number, check the diffs before and after it, and once you find the one that looks right, use a `git reset --soft` to move the `HEAD` of the new branch there, then wrap it up with something like

```
git commit -m"retroactively creating new branch for files received via email"
```

Comment: I like the counting-changed-files approach but your text should probably describe it that way, diff --stat|wc -l is not counting changed lines.

Comment: This is a classic "XY Problem" scenario (not my terminology... look it up). Look at the OP's problem description, then realize my one-liner actually solves their actual problem (X: find the correct base commit) instead of an obstacle with a presumed solution (Y: tell me the number of lines changed).